# How Apache Kafka working with Spring boot application with OAuth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, apache-kafka

This is producer

```
private void insertQueueEmail(EmailSendingRequestDTO emailSendingRequestDTO) {
    sender.kafkaSendEmail(emailSendingRequestDTO);
}
```

This is consumer

```
  // @PreAuthorize("isAuthentication()")
  @KafkaListener(topics = "emailTopic", groupId = "foo")
  public ResponseEntity<GECEorderResponseMessageDTO> insertEmailQueue(@RequestBody 
         EmailSendingRequestDTO emailSendingRequestDTO) {
       ...... //do something
  }
```

Its work correctly, But when add @PreAuthorize("isAuthentication()") before @KafkaListener for validating access token I get 404 not found

I need to know how can I using Kafka to send message to consumer and working with @PreAuthorize annotation

Comment: Whom do you need to authorize to define a listener? I think you're a bit off-context with Kafka listener and `@PreAuthorize`

Comment: @HasanCanSaral I don't know what do you mean, please explain.

Comment: I'm assuming that there's no `Authorization` object in the context when defining the listener (like when you put `@PreAuthorize` in front of a `@RestController` method, you have a `Authentication` object). That's why you are getting the error. You cannot achieve what you're trying to like that.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral How can I get that Authorization object ?

Comment: Basically, you cannot, because you don't have a `HttpServletRequest` in context when defining your listener. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral  I need to attach access token which generated from my Authentication Service (OAuth) and post to Kafka listener and (with @PreAuthorize) and spring can validate that token from Redis (access token pool)